# Ext.grid.Tree not found

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I am trying to use Ext.grid.Tree in my ExtJs project.
But it looks like 'tree' component is not added to extjs project by default.

I created new ExtJs application using "ext-gen app -i"

Then I added "requires: ['Ext.grid.Tree']" to MyExtGenApp.Application.
Try to build the application "sencha app build"
And got an error:

```
[ERR] D:\WORKSPACES\my-ext-gen-app\node_modules\@sencha\cmd\dist\plugin.xml:333: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\WORKSPACES\my-ext-gen-app\node_modules\@sencha\cmd\dist\ant\build\app\build-impl.xml:387: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\WORKSPACES\my-ext-gen-app\node_modules\@sencha\cmd\dist\ant\build\app\init-impl.xml:436: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for D:\WORKSPACES\my-ext-gen-app\app\desktop\src\Application.js::ClassRequire::Ext.grid.Tree
```

I did not change anything exept "requires: ['Ext.grid.Tree']".

Looks like "ext-modern-treegrid" node-module is not included to project.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `Premium/Enterprise` product Tier?

Comment: I have not. But Ext.grid.Tree is not marked as commercial component. And it is included to ExtJs Comuniti Edition (in @sencha/ext-modern-treegrid node module)

Comment: Do you add package like `npm i --save @sencha/ext-modern-treegrid` ? Here i see is Premium/Enterprise : https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/7.2.0/guides/using_npm/npm_packages.html

Comment: Yes, I did it. It is not ExtReact project, but ExtJs. Here is marked as Standart not Premium: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0-CE/guides/using_systems/using_npm/extjs_packages.html

Answer (score 0):

For modernt toolkit, as it is [stated in the docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.grid.Tree.html), `Ext.tree.Grid` requires separate NPM Package @sencha/ext-modern-treegrid.

So, you have to install it with `npm i --save @sencha/ext-modern-treegrid` and add its name "treegrid" to requires in the app.json (*you check ExtJS package name in the \node_modules\@sencha\{package}\package.json, "sencha" section*):

```
"requires": [
    "treegrid"
],
```

This should fix errors like:

> Failed to resolve dependency Ext.grid.Tree

> com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.grid.Tree